# Help me with PHP regex

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace, preg-match

I want to remove the `_8` from the `$thumbnail`

```
$thumbnail = "http://d2dsfsd.humbnails/20415/33-d148-45b1-9098-11e5c/thumbnail_8.jpg";
```

I must have been clear..

sometimes `$thumbnail` might have `_10` or `_100`.. how do i handle then?

Comment: always the _8 or any number ? _1212121.jpg ?

Answer (score 2):

or to be a bit more flexible

```
$thumbnail = preg_replace('#_\d+(?=\.jpg$)#', '', $thumbnail);
```

`(?=\.jpg$)` is a positive look ahead that ensures that after the `_\d+` there is `.jpg` and then the end of the string.

`\d` is a digit

`+` means one or more

`$` matches the end of the string

Answer (score 1):

Will it always be "_8"? If so just use:

```
$thumbnail = str_replace("_8.jpg", ".jpg", $thumbnail);
```

Or regex can be used to replace any series of numbers:

```
$thumbnail = preg_replace("#_[0-9]+\.jpg$#", ".jpg", $thumbnail);
```

Comment: I must have been clear..

sometimes $thumbnail might have _10 or _100..

Answer (score 1):

Assuming no other underscores in the filename, you can do this:

```
$thumbnail = preg_replace('/_\d+/', '', $thumbnail);
```

fairly simple regex; removes underscore followed by any number of digits.

If you might have other occurrences of underscore followed by digits, and you only want to remove the one at the end, it gets a bit more complex, as you need to match the `.jpg` but not remove it. You'd do something like this:

```
$thumbnail = preg_replace('/_\d+\.jpg$/', '.jpg', $thumbnail);
```

This removes the `.jpg` as well as the underscore and digits, but then puts the `.jpg` back again in the replacement string. Note, I've also added a `$` to tie it to the end of the string to make double-sure it's matching the right part of the string, even if it's got other occurrences that match.

Answer (score 0):

This is fairly simple

```
$thumbnail = preg_replace('/_\d+\.jpg/', '.jpg', $thumbnail);
```

Comment: I must have been clear..

sometimes $thumbnail might have _10 or _100.. how do i handle then?

Comment: see my edits - if it is always a digit this will work

Answer (score 0):

For variable integers, you can use:

```
$thumbnail = preg_replace( '~_([\d]+)\.jpg$~', ".jpg", $thumbnail );
```